# Underscores in RedirectMatch 301

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I have two URLs. First is

```
example.com/upload/book1_e
```

and second is

```
example.com/upload/book1_e_h
```

I want to redirect these two URLs to two different URLs using RedirectMatch 301 but right now both URLs are redirecting to same URL.

Comment: what code you tried to do

Comment: RerdirectMatch 301 /upload/book1_e http://www.example.com/upload/book1            
RerdirectMatch 301 /upload/book1_e_h http://www.example.com/upload/book2

Comment: redirecting using htaccess or routes or redirect function?

Comment: Both urls are redirecting to  example.com/upload/book1

Comment: @Kyslik redirecting using htaccess

Comment: have you tried RewriteRule in htacess

Comment: @HossamAldeenAhmed no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution:
If I change the sequence of urls then its working fine.
maybe second url redirect to same redirection url of first because in second url if it matches to first url then it  will not check the complete url.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/upload/book1_e$ example.com/upload/book1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/upload/book1_e_h$ example.com/upload/book2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I got the solution by changing the sequence of redirection urls.